# Identity Server missing ReturnUrl parameter on /connect/authorize

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, duende

I'm using Duende Identity Server library in C#, and I've configured a Client that has the allowed grant type of code. Here is that client configuration:

This IdentityServer hosts a login page that acts as a Single Sign On for other applications. Then I have a React SPA that uses oidc-client to access the Identity Server, so that users are able to login on the Identity Server and then be redirect back towards the React SPA. My issue is that when the React SPA makes a request to the endpoint /connect/authorize, the URL returned by the IdentityServer does not include the standard ReturnUrl query parameter, like so:

"https://localhost:44333/?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id...."
Instead, it returns this URL:

"https://localhost:44334/connect/authorize?client_id"

This is the client configuration in C#:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TcFw.png)

This is OIDC configuration in oidc-client:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysdTf.png)

Does anyone know why this might be happening?